# How to Resubmit app aab file after getting rejection from google play store?

Tags: flutter, dart, apk, release, publish

I have upload an app but got rejected due to app’s use of QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission.Now I want to upload a new version of aab file into playstore how to do that/How to remove my previous release and resubmit new release.

I had tried removing the package from marged manifest file, from my project and build another appbundle for this new release. Hope it works this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove query all packages permission just add new build and modify it from local.properties file to increase number of build to be accepted
If you upload this version ,old version will be deactivate automatically and you can remove it from play store

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).